# Mexican states SHP without coastline?

Tags: shapefile, data, administrative-boundaries, mexico

Is there a shapefile anywhere showing Mexican boundaries (national & state) that are NOT clipped to the coastline? Either polygons showing the maritime boundary, or polylines showing only the land borders without the coastline would work.

I prefer to use the INEGI vectors, but I've only found those with coastlines.

Comment: Have you looked at Natural Earth?: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/

Comment: I have, but it doesn't look like they have boundaries. Also, I'd like something of better resolution than 1:10m, if possible. (This project would display at 500k or 250k.)

Comment: Maybe http://gcmd.nasa.gov/records/GCMD_MRJBoundary_CD.html or http://www.marineregions.org/gazetteer.php?p=details&id=8429

Comment: Thanks, I saw those too. The first is a CD rom for sale, and the second is water only, no land areas. I'm looking for something to match the US TIGER files and Canadian census digital files that show states and provinces including their offshore area (so that their shorelines don't conflict with the world shoreline layer I'm using).

Answer (score 1):

To get land borders as lines without the shore, you could dissolve the INEGI polygons for the whole country, and convert to polyline. Then, convert the borders to polyline as well, and "erase" these by the country-wide (i.e., shore) lines you just made.

Comment: Yep, that's just what I ended up doing. I would have preferred to keep the polygons with their attributes, but for my purposes this works just as well. Thanks, all!